# Trouble implementing the CIDR notation mask into my ip address output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on my own personal task that helps me extract the ip addresses that start with "inet addr" from the "ip address" command in linux. I also wanted to extract the interfaces associated with each ip address.

For example something like this:

Interface name | IP address
eth0 | 192.168.2.100/24
eth1 | 10.10.2.100/20

Here is the following output i'm working with:

> eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr b8:ac:6f:65:31:e5 inet
> addr:192.168.2.100 Bcast:192.168.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr:
> fe80::baac:6fff:fe65:31e5/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST
> MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:2697529 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0
> frame:0 TX packets:2630541 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
> collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:2159382827 (2.0 GiB) TX
> bytes:1389552776 (1.2 GiB) Interrupt:17
>
> eth1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr b8:ac:6f:65:53:e5 inet
> addr:10.10.2.100 Bcast:10.10.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr:
> fe80::baac:6fff:ff65:31e5/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST
> MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:2697529 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0
> frame:0 TX packets:2630541 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
> collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:2159382827 (2.0 GiB) TX
> bytes:1389552776 (1.2 GiB) Interrupt:17
>
> lo Link encap:Local Loopback inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6
> addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1 RX
> packets:2849 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:2849
> errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX
> bytes:2778290 (2.6 MiB) TX bytes:2778290 (2.6 MiB)
>
> ppp0 Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol inet addr:10.1.3.105
> P-t-P:10.0.31.18 Mask:255.255.255.255 UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP
> MULTICAST MTU:1496 Metric:1 RX packets:102800 errors:0 dropped:0
> overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:63437 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0
> carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 RX bytes:148532544 (141.6 MiB) TX
> bytes:4425518 (4.2 MiB)
>
> vmnet1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01 inet
> addr:192.168.47.1 Bcast:192.168.47.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr:
> fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST
> MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
> TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0
> txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> vmnet8 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08 inet
> addr:172.16.232.1 Bcast:172.16.232.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr:
> fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST
> MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
> TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0
> txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> vmnet9 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:01:08 inet
> addr:172.16.233.1 Bcast:172.16.233.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr:
> fe80::250:76ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST
> MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
> TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0
> txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> vmnet10 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:02:08 inet
> addr:172.16.234.1 Bcast:172.16.234.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr:
> fe80::250:86ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST
> MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
> TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0
> txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

Here is the following code I have done and worked with:

```
import re

with open('rawdata.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()



s = []
subnetM = re.findall(r'(?<=Mask:255.)(.*)', data)
position = 0
for i in subnetM:
    if i == "255.255.0":
        s.insert(position, "/24")
    if i == "255.255.255":
        s.insert(position, "/32")
    if i == "0.0.0":
        s.insert(position, "/8")
    position = position + 1

c = []
for paragraph in data.split('\n\n'):

    ma = re.compile("^(\S+).*?inet addr:(\S+)", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    result = ma.match(paragraph)

    if result != None:
        result = ma.match(paragraph)

        interface = result.group(1)
        ip = result.group(2)

        c.append([interface, ip])

print("Interface name | IP address")

for (interface, ip) in c:
    print(interface, ' | ', ip)
```

Although this works fine, I can't seem to extract the subnet mask prefixes such as /24, /25, /26 with the ip addresses.

Here is the following output I get:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2hPp.png)

Comment: Do not parse the output for humans with regular expressions! Run the command as `ip --json address` to produce a machine readable JSON. The JSON is a list of nested dict with all the data nicely structured. Tip: install the `jq` utiliy and run `ip --json address | jq .` on the command line to see the structure pretty formatted (and in color). BTW, the `jq` alone can probably solve the task if you are willing to learn a new tool.

Comment: Yeah I have looked into that, but I am currently trying to work with regex as I am a beginner with it. Just trying to further develop my coding skills and such

Comment: To select the right tool for a task is one of the skills to be learned. Do you know the insider joke about regex: "... Now they have two problems." ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a complete working program to show the advantage of JSON output:

```
import json
import subprocess

with subprocess.Popen("/usr/sbin/ip --json address".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    ip = json.load(proc.stdout)
for iface in ip:
    name = iface['ifname']
    for info in iface['addr_info']:
        print(f"{name} | {info['local']}/{info['prefixlen']}")
```